# Unable to cast object of type 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException' to type 'System.IConvertible'.'

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

i can't find the error, and i been working for weeks with this problem, and i hope that you can help me to solve it.

This one is my class that makes the access to tha database

```
namespace Monsterafood
{
    public class clsDataAccess : ClsWebConfig
    {

        public static DataTable ExecuteSelectCommand(DbCommand command)
        {
            DataTable table;
            try
            {
                command.Connection.Open();
                DbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                table = new DataTable();
                table.Load(reader);
                reader.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                //clsUtilities.LogError(ex);
                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                command.Connection.Close();
            }
            return table;
        }

        public static DbCommand CreateCommand()
        {
            string dataProviderName = ClsWebConfig.DbProviderName;
            string connectionString = ClsWebConfig.DbConnectionString;
            DbProviderFactory factory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(dataProviderName);
            DbConnection conn = factory.CreateConnection();
            conn.ConnectionString = connectionString;
            DbCommand comm = conn.CreateCommand();
            return comm;
        }

        public static int ExecuteNonQuery(DbCommand command)
        {
            int affectedRows = -1;
            try
            {
                command.Connection.Open();
                affectedRows = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                command.Connection.Close();
            }
            return affectedRows;
        }

        public static string ExecuteScalar(DbCommand command)
        {
            string value = "";
            try
            {
                command.Connection.Open();
                value = command.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                command.Connection.Close();
            }
            return value;
        }

    }
}
```

and this is the method that call the class

```
public static string inserta(string id_add, string nombre, string precio)
        {
            DbCommand comm = clsDataAccess.CreateCommand();
            comm.CommandText= "INSERT INTO temporalcrepa(id_add, nombre, precio) VALUES(" + id_add + ", '" + nombre + "', " + precio + "); ";
            string x= clsDataAccess.ExecuteScalar(comm);
            return x;
        }
```

I'm using c# and javascript and my database is mysql.
Thank you so much to help me with the problem

Comment: your code is vulnerable to **sql injection** please check for **prepared stemenst with parameters**

Comment: If you're trying to troubleshoot the "Unable to cast object of type 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException' to type 'System.IConvertible'.'" error, please paste the exception details with _full call stack_ into your question: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noexceptiondetails/

Answer (score 0):

You are executing a insert statement calling executeScalar(), you want to call ExecuteNonQuery() not Scalar.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I first use ExecuteNonQuery() but i have the same error so i tried with a different        
   public static int inserta(string id_add, string nombre, string precio)
        {
            DbCommand comm = clsDataAccess.CreateCommand();
            comm.CommandText= "INSERT INTO temporalcrepa(id_add, nombre, precio) VALUES(" + id_add + ", '" + nombre + "', " + precio + "); ";
            int x = clsDataAccess.ExecuteNonQuery(comm);
            return x;
        }

Comment: add a break point step through your code, find out where the exception is being thrown. Did the conn open successfully? etc.

Comment: Yes i use the break point to see the problem and when is inside the method ExecuteNonQuery  in this part is show me the error affectedRows = command.ExecuteNonQuery();

Comment: can you update your post with your current code and showing the error? Does the record get inserted?